# Google adwords - Retrieving Clicks, ... from keywords?

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm creating my own bidmanager and stumbled upon a certain problem. I am able to retrieve the statistics (so clicks, ...) from the Campaigns/adgroups but I can't seem to find anything related to retrieving the statstics per keyword WITHOUT generating a report?

I'm currently able to retrieve the keywors name and matchtype, by using the AdGeoupCriterionService. However, I don't see a possibility in there to retrieve the statistics per keyword.

Upon googling, a lot of stuff is found which is using the statsSelector which is, in the latest version, not supported anymore

Any idea on how to retrieve those stats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see them in the AdgroupCriterionService 
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/selectorfields#v201209-AdGroupCriterionService

or you can download a Keyword Performance report:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports#keywords